# Libre office Calc and Hour duration format?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am so confused by the format Calc is expecting. I am former Numbers user(Apples version of Calc)
what am trying to achieve is to regard a cell that has a single digit as an hour and append "H" to the end.

For example, `3` will be reformatted to `3 H`

Right now I am getting some weird calculations. I've tried applying

`HH" H"` to cell that has a single digit, it turns the cell into `00 H`

```
HH" H"  22:33:22     22 H
HH" H"  221122       00 H
HH" H"  222          00 H
HH" H"  2            00 H
```

It keeps inserting 000s into the cell, the only one that gives me some result is the first one.
but having to type  `22:33:22`  for every cell is not ideal. Instead how can I get calc to just regard any digit as an hour?

Comment: Also posted at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/296084/calc-and-hour-duration-format/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates and times in spreadsheets are commonly stored as floating-point numbers, with 1.0 equal one day.

You can divide the value of the hour by 24 and format the result as time.

BTW, the format `H" H"` will give you single digit numbers if the value is less than 10.